# Kivy returns "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'" when accessing ListProperty

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, listproperty

I'm trying to create a screen that displays an image file whose path is stored in a ListProperty. I understand that the error message indicates that Kivy is trying to access the value before the ListProperty is created, but I don't know how to fix this.

Here's a snippet from my main.py script where the property is initialized to an empty list containing a single empty string and the build method is called:

```
presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    image_list = ListProperty([''])

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

And here is a section of main.kv where the property is used:

```
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Picture:
            source: app.image_string.pop()
```

The exception thrown is as follows:

```
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 71:
 ...
      69:        orientation: 'horizontal'
      70:        Picture:
 >>   71:            source: app.image_string.pop()
      72:
```

Any guidance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**  Reader FIns pointed out that I was calling **image_string** instead of image_list, but even after making the correction, I get the same error:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Picture:
        source: app.image_list.pop()
 BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 71:
```

And ...

```
 BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 71:
 ...
      69:        orientation: 'horizontal'
      70:        Picture:
 >>   71:            source: app.image_list.pop()
```

Comment: in app you declared `image_list`, but you used `image_string` in main.kv

Comment: Oop! You're right. I was experimenting with ListProperty and StringProperty but that still doesn't solve my problem. Even if I correct that syntax error, I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

loading kivy design language inside the build method works in this example:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.properties import ListProperty 
from kivy.base import Builder

class MainApp(App):
    image_list = ListProperty([''])

    def build(self):
        presentation = Builder.load_string(""" 
Screen:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            source: app.image_list.pop()
    """)

        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks Flns!  I'll give that a shot. I think I'd prefer to maintain only one file anyway so using a build string is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks a million FIns!! I've been pulling my hair out for two days over this and you solution worked perfectly! I really appreciate you assisting me on this.